# Data calculation in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have:

```
    A1   A2  Random data  Random data2  Average    Stddev
0  0.1  2.0          300          3000     1.05  1.343503
1  0.5  4.5         4500           450     2.50  2.828427
2  3.0  1.2          800            80     2.10  1.272792
3  9.0  9.0          900            90     9.00  0.000000
```

And would like to add a column 'ColumnX' that needs to have the values calculated as :

```
ColumnX = min(df['Random data']-df['Average'],df[Random data2]-
df[Stddev])/3.0*df['A2'])
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
```

Comment: Show us what you think the output should be.  In other words, we want to see explicitly how you think the calculation ought to be carried out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error has to do with pandas preferring bitwise operators and using the built in min function isn't going to work row wise.

A potential solution would be to make two new calculated columns then using the pandas dataframe .min method.

```
df['calc_col_1'] = df['Random data']-df['Average']
df['calc_col_2'] = (df['Random data2']-df['Stddev'])/(3.0*df['A2'])
df['min_col'] = df[['calc_col_1','calc_col_2']].min(axis=1)
```

The method min(axis=1) will find the min between the two columns by row then assigned to the new column.  This way is efficient because you're using numpy vectorization, and it is easier to read.

Comment: Thank You.  I just had modify: df['calc_col_2'] = (df['Random data2']-df['Stddev'])  and added: df['colx']=df['min_col']/(3.0*df['A2']) for the math to be correct.  Thanks again.